# c - передать в функцию один элемент массива структур

Tags: c, структуры, динамические-массивы

Запутался в указателях. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передать и обработать внутри функции один элемент из массива структур? Как правильно обращаться внутри функции к элементам переданной структуры?

Краткое описание кода. Чистый Си:

```
typedef struct {
    // Weight in grams
    size_t weight;
    // Name of Thing
    char name[255];

} Things;

void print_function(Things *things)
{
    // Работает корректно
    printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",things->name,things->weight);

}

void print_struct(Things **things)
{
    // Вызывает Segmentation fault:
    printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",(*things)[0].name,(*things)[0].weight);
    // Такой вариант тоже:
    printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",(*things)->name,(*things)->weight);

}
```

Вызов:

```
print_function(&things[i]);

print_struct(&things[i]);
```

Код полностью. Модель сделана по мотивам реальной программы. Поэтому важно оставить структуру вызова одной функции из другой в нетронутом виде:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    // Weight in grams
    size_t weight;
    // Name of Thing
    char name[255];

} Things;

void print_function(Things *things)
{
    // Работает корректно
    printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",things->name,things->weight);

}

void print_struct(Things **things)
{
    // Приводит к Segmentation fault:
    printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",(*things)[0].name,(*things)[0].weight);
    // Такой вариант тоже приводит к Segmentation fault:
    printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",(*things)->name,(*things)->weight);

}

void add_new_thing(Things **things,size_t *size)
{

    size_t index = *size;

    if(index == 0) {
        (*size) = 1;
        *things = (Things*)calloc((*size),sizeof(Things));
        if (*things == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't allocate memory! %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        (*size) += 1;
        Things *temp = (Things*)realloc(*things,(*size)*sizeof(Things));
        if(temp != NULL) {
            *things = temp;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't reallocate memory! %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // Zeroing of new structure's elements
        (*things)[index].name[0] = '\0';
        (*things)[index].weight = 0;
    }

}

void another_function(Things **things, size_t *size)
{
    // Add one element to the array of structures
    add_new_thing(things,size);
    const char *str1 = "Boiled buckwheat";
    strncpy((*things)[*size-1].name, str1, strlen(str1) + 1);
    (*things)[*size-1].weight = 1500;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n",(*things)[i].name,(*things)[i].weight);
    }

    // Add one more element to the array of structures
    add_new_thing(things, size);
    const char *str2 = "A toy";
    strncpy((*things)[*size-1].name, str2, strlen(str2) + 1);
    (*things)[*size-1].weight = 350;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        print_struct(&things[i]);
    }
}

void some_function(Things **things, size_t *size)
{
    // To pass the array of structures to another function
    another_function(things, size);
}


int main(void)
{

    // Create NULL pointer for the array of structures
    Things *things = NULL;

    // Add size of structures' array which will be allocated within add_new_thing() function
    size_t size = 0;

    // Call some function
    some_function(&things, &size);

    printf("Print results:\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        print_function(&things[i]);
    }
    free(things);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Сборка:

```
cc -std=c11
```

Comment: Попросту вызовите в `another_function()`  вместо `print_struct()` корректно работающую `print_function()` вот таким       `print_function((*things) + i);` образом.

Comment: `printf("Thing: %s, weight: %zu\n", things[0]->name, things[0]->weight);` если очень хочется заморачиваться с указателем на указатель.

Comment: Большое спасибо, @0andriy! Реализовал через print_function((*things) + i); и после двух дней мучений и поисков ответа всё, наконец, заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как исправить, чтобы это заработало:

Убрать строчку

```
    print_struct(&things[i]);
```

И заменить на:

```
   Things *tmp=&((*things)[i]);
    print_struct(&tmp);
```

Дело в том, что когда мы разыменовываем указатель на указатель, то меняя индекс в things[i], мы фактически смещаемся на размер указателя, а не желаемой структурки, как того предполагает код.

Как следствие, надо разыменовать наш указатель на указатель, его тип поменяется на простой указатель указанного типа, с которым можно будет делать адресную арифметику или к которому можно обращаться по индексу. Мы берем от этого указатель. Но так как нам надо указатель на указатель, то промежуточный указатель надо где-то сохранить, для этого и есть tmp.

А вообще, на мой личный взгляд, код просто отвратительный. Как правило, надо определиться:

1. Или у нас есть указатель на массив указателей, что позволяет затем делать &things[i] или просто things[i]. В этом же случае удобно сделать какой-то "конструктор" вида add_new_thing, где обычно и заполнение данными происходит. И хотя гораздо удобнее с таким работать, это занимает немного больше памяти, которые уходят на сами указатели.
2. Или у нас все в одном куске памяти, как тут, но для этого пляска с указателем на указатель совершенно не нужна. Для этого надо выучить адресную арифметику. И совершенно не нужно постоянно оперировать указателем на указатель.

Данный код содержит в себе сразу 2 подхода одновременно, собирая от них худшее, от того и проблема.

**Новое:**

Пример первого варианта:

```js
Things *add_new_thing(Things *prev, char *name, int weight) {
    Things * new_item = malloc(sizeof(Things));
    if (!new_item) {
      fprintf(stderr, "shit happened\n");
      abort();
    }
    // Опционально можно занулить нашу структурку, по желанию. Или вообще брать чистое через calloc - дело вкуса и стиля
    memset(new_item, 0, sizeof(Things));
    
    // копируем в нашу структурку пришедшие данные. Иногда имеет смысл сделать strdup или просто присвоить пришедшую переменную, в зависимости от условий
    strncpy(new_item->name,name,sizeof(((Things*)0)->name));
    new_item->weight=weight;

    // немного магии
    prev->next=new_item;
    return(new_item);
}
```

В данном случае мы выделяем независимый кусочек памяти, не трогая другие, делаем с ним что захотим. Но куда его деть? Обычно его просто возвращают как ответ, но раз у нас функция названа как add, то надо как-то и куда-то его добавить. Самое простое - это добавляем поле next, которое в себе будет содержать указатель на следующий элемент. Называется такой "трюк" LinkedList, это одна из базовых структур данных. Конечно, обращаться к записям как к элементу массива нельзя, зато можно итерировать элементы последовательно и не нужно писать код для выделения памяти под указатели (нужно только как-то родить корневой элемент).

Comment: Благодарю за подробное разъяснение, @bukkojot! Солидарен полностью, что код монструозен! Я относительно недавно в языке и пока далёк от понимания всех сишных тонкостей. Вас не затруднит на примерах в коде показать подходы касательно пунктов 1 и 2. Посыл понятен, но суть понимания ускользает без примеров.

Comment: Если убрать цирк с указателем на указатель, то ты фактически реализовал вариант 2, когда все в одном куске. Вариант с выделением указателей будет с предварительным выделением памяти под указатели, а затем уже выделением под структурки. Пример в новой версии поста.

Comment: Пример понял. Даже понял, что такая магическая конструкция prev->next=new_item; нужна для рекурсивного удаления  массива структур. Подобные примеры встречал в сети. Остался маленький вопрос. Как обращаться к элементам этого массива структур внутри функций? А именно: присваивать значение и разыменовывать (lvalue,rvalue)?

Comment: Не для удаления, а для обхода всех элементов. Обращаться можно именно так: перебирая каждый элемент. Подробности в википедии по запросу LinkedList